# How to recover an overwritten directory in cloudera

Tags: unix, hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql

I was using HIVE in my Cloudera VM.

I used the below command to write my output of my HQL statement to an output file.

```
`INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/cloudera/output'
SELECT * from City; ....`
```

After getting the output i found that all my files in the cloudera directory got over written. i can see only my output file in the path.

Is there any way i can undo or recover all the files that i've lost.

My hive.log file is below for any reference

Comment: It is not possible to recover a over written file... It is same as normal file ... you can  try some third party recovery tool but not adivicable on  prod

Answer (score 0):

You can try to search into hive trash folder (/user/hive/.Trash). I think that you will find your lost file.